# Weird instance variable behaviour in Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's consider the following example:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base

  def engine
    @engine ||= Engine.new(self)
  end

end

class Engine

  def initialize(vehicle)
    @vehicle = vehicle
  end

  def model
    @vehicle.model
  end

end
```

and what I don't understand is that when I go to the console and do something like that:

```
car = Car.last
car.engine.model  # => 'V8'
```

and then

```
car.model = 'V6'
```

I get

```
car.engine.model  # => 'V6'
```

It's obviously a simplified example but anyway, can anyone explain why I get a different engine model name in the last line of code? Isn't it supposed to use the @engine variable and return the previous engine model name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No surprise here. You initialize `Engine` instance with `car` object, so `@vehicle` instance variable have reference to the same object as `car` local variable. No wonder then that if you modify `car` object, `@engine` object will be modified in the same way.

Comment: I see, thank you. Is engine method safe the way I implemented it or it's better to create a new instance of engine with every call just to make sure that I always get the correct information in case some of the car attributes change?

Comment: @JustMichael it's no difference at this aspect. If you instantiate `Engine` every time you call `Car#engine` method, it would still return changed `Car` attributes.